# Cannot call void user defined function inside main function in C programming

Tags: c

When I try to run the below program

```
#include<stdio.h>
/* demo.c:  My first C program on a Linux */
void main()
{
    getString();
}

void getString()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

I get the below error:

```
sample.c:8:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘getString’ [enabled by default]
 void getString()
      ^
sample.c:5:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘getString’ was here
     getString();
```

I cannot find out why this error is showing in Compilation time.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll find many more similar questions and answers with a SO search for `[c] conflicting types for previous implicit declaration`

Comment: declare `void getString()` as prototype before main function or define the `void getString()` function above main function

Comment: Changed my code to this ` #include<stdio.h>
/* demo.c:  My first C program on a Linux */

void getString()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}

void main()
{
    getString();
}` and now its working fine.. thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Program is unable to get the declaration of getString() method show just declare your method before calling it inside main(). What you can do is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
/* demo.c:  My first C program on a Linux */
void getString()
{
printf("Hello World");
}

void main()
{
getString();
}
```